# How to load Avro File to BigQuery tables with columns having 'Timestamp' type

Tags: google-bigquery

By default, Avro doesn't support timestamp but I can have 'Epoch' time values having 'Long' type in the file. What I want is to load those values in 'Timestamp' format while loading the Avro file data to Bigquery table using command line tool.
For example : I have a column having value `1511253927` and I want this value to be loaded as `2017-11-21 00:00:00` using command line tool.
Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to run a query with your file as a federated data source and use TIMESTAMP_SECONDS standard SQL function to convert values.